# I need efficient Django ORM code to reduce query hitting

Tags: python, django

I am developing various statistical dashboards with Django, Python.
A lot of filtered objects from each table and pass them to the template. But the result of the Debug-Toolbar is terrible.
I need to change my code that is Hitting my database more efficiently.
** And this project is based on the models created by inspectDB on the server that is already developed.

- Django 2.2
- Linux server, MariaDB

## Model

```py
class Consult(models.Model):
    consult_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    consult_type = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    booking_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    booking_time_unix = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    dr_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    uid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    session_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    consult_action = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cancel_reason = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    notify_cnt = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    consult_begin_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    consult_end_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    img_url1 = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    img_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    img_url2 = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    img_name2 = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    img_url3 = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    img_name3 = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'consult'
```

## View

```py
@login_required
def index(request):

    today = datetime.date.today()
    weekday = today.weekday()
    last_monday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=weekday, weeks=1)
    last_sunday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=weekday) -         
    datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    this_monday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=weekday)
    tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    today_lastyear = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=365)

    # Fast Consult Applied Total(consult_type=2)
    fast_consult_begin_lastweek = Consult.objects.filter(created_at__gte=last_monday, created_at__lte=last_sunday, consult_type=2).count()
    fast_consult_begin_thisweek = Consult.objects.filter(created_at__gte=this_monday, created_at__lte=tomorrow, consult_type=2).count()
    fast_consult_begin_variation = fast_consult_begin_thisweek - fast_consult_begin_lastweek

    # Fast Consult Finished(status=5, consult_type=2)
    fast_consult_complete_lastweek = Consult.objects.filter(created_at__gte=last_monday, created_at__lte=last_sunday, consult_type=2, status=5).count()
    fast_consult_complete_thisweek = Consult.objects.filter(created_at__gte=this_monday, created_at__lte=tomorrow, consult_type=2, status=5).count()
    fast_consult_complete_variation = fast_consult_complete_thisweek - fast_consult_complete_lastweek

    # Fast Consult Canceled(status=9, consult_type=2)
    fast_consult_cancel_lastweek = Consult.objects.filter(created_at__gte=last_monday, created_at__lte=last_sunday, consult_type=2, status=9).count()
    fast_consult_cancel_thisweek = Consult.objects.filter(created_at__gte=this_monday, created_at__lte=tomorrow, consult_type=2, status=9).count()
    fast_consult_cancel_variation = fast_consult_cancel_thisweek - fast_consult_cancel_lastweek

    # Reservation Consult Applied Total(consult_type=1)
    book_consult_begin_lastweek = Consult.objects.filter(created_at__gte=last_monday, created_at__lte=last_sunday, consult_type=1).count()
    book_consult_begin_thisweek = Consult.objects.filter(created_at__gte=this_monday, created_at__lte=tomorrow, consult_type=1).count()
    book_consult_begin_variation = book_consult_begin_thisweek - book_consult_begin_lastweek

    # Reservation Consult Completed(status=5, consult_type=1)
    book_consult_complete_lastweek = Consult.objects.filter(created_at__gte=last_monday, created_at__lte=last_sunday, consult_type=1, status=5).count()
    book_consult_complete_thisweek = Consult.objects.filter(created_at__gte=this_monday, created_at__lte=tomorrow, consult_type=1, status=5).count()
    book_consult_complete_variation = book_consult_complete_thisweek - book_consult_complete_lastweek

    # Reservation Consult Canceled(status=9,consult_type=1)
    book_consult_cancel_lastweek = Consult.objects.filter(created_at__gte=last_monday, created_at__lte=last_sunday, consult_type=1, status=9).count()
    book_consult_cancel_thisweek = Consult.objects.filter(created_at__gte=this_monday, created_at__lte=tomorrow, consult_type=1, status=9).count()
    book_consult_cancel_variation = book_consult_cancel_thisweek - book_consult_cancel_lastweek

context = {
        'fast_consult_begin_lastweek':fast_consult_begin_lastweek,
        'fast_consult_begin_thisweek':fast_consult_begin_thisweek,
        'fast_consult_begin_variation':fast_consult_begin_variation,
        'fast_consult_complete_lastweek':fast_consult_complete_lastweek,
        'fast_consult_complete_thisweek':fast_consult_complete_thisweek,
        'fast_consult_complete_variation':fast_consult_complete_variation,
        'fast_consult_cancel_lastweek': fast_consult_cancel_lastweek,
        'fast_consult_cancel_thisweek': fast_consult_cancel_thisweek,
        'fast_consult_cancel_variation': fast_consult_cancel_variation,
        'book_consult_begin_lastweek': book_consult_begin_lastweek,
        'book_consult_begin_thisweek': book_consult_begin_thisweek,
        'book_consult_begin_variation': book_consult_begin_variation,
        'book_consult_complete_lastweek': book_consult_complete_lastweek,
        'book_consult_complete_thisweek': book_consult_complete_thisweek,
        'book_consult_complete_variation': book_consult_complete_variation,
        'book_consult_cancel_lastweek': book_consult_cancel_lastweek,
        'book_consult_cancel_thisweek': book_consult_cancel_thisweek,
        'book_consult_cancel_variation': book_consult_cancel_variation,
    }
    return render(request, 'main_app/index.html', context)
```

In the state of sending each as above, according to Debug-Toolbar, many duplicate queries occur.
What should I do?

Comment: The queries all look unique, what indexes are in use on the table?

Comment: consult_id(PK), booking_time, dr_id, status, uid are indexes in this table, all of index type are BTree.